# Problemas al refrescar datos en front PDO PHP

Tags: php7, pdo

Vengo presentando un inconveniente con un sistema y es que al momento de hacer un cambio en BD, ya sea un update o un insert y refrescar el front o recargar el front para poder visualizar esos nuevos datos, nunca me refrescan los datos, me toca cerrar la session y volver a ingresar session, para poder ver los datos actualizados, alguien sabe que puede pasar?

Comment: Puede que tu sistema usa datos precargados, por eso, cada vez que inicia sesion, se visualizan los insert o updates que hayas ingresado.

Comment: Tengo los datos de usuario en una variable de sesion $_SESSION['login'] se debe refrescar la session o algo asi?

Comment: lo que debes de refrescar es la consulta que haces a tu BD